# Shortest string representation for Int32

Tags: c#, asp.net, algorithm, string

I need to convert an `Int32` to a code that has to be entered on a web form. To keep it simple for the visitors, this code needs to be as simple and short as possible.

Does anybody know a good algorithm for converting an `Int32` to the shortest string representation possible using only [0-9] and [A-Z]?

Comment: @Darin, presumably a "string representation [...] using only [0-9] and [A-Z]"

Comment: I don't understand, isn't the `Int32.ToString()` method sufficient in this case?

Comment: Customers get a snailmail mailing where the code is printed (ie. "A1B2C3") that they have to enter in the web form,.

Comment: @Darin, that wouldn't be the shortest possible representation.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/balamurali_balaji.aspx simly adapt it to Base36

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *could* encode to base-36, but for everyone's sanity (not least your users, dealing with I vs 1, O vs 0 etc), I suggest just sticking to hex; plus it is built in:

```
    int value = 22334;
    string hex = Convert.ToString(value, 16); // 573e
    value = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16);
```

Comment: Add to this that base 36 can still require 7 digits, so gains you very little over hex (8 digits).

Answer (score 6):

A [base 36](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36) representation is what you want. This uses both alphabetical and numerical symbols to encode numbers, for a very compact representation.

Comment: Base 36 means you could end up with I10O010, which isn't particularly 'simple for visitors'...

Answer (score 1):

Just an example, I haven't looked up all the details for this.

Given a 32 bit int:

Split it into 8x4 bits

A 4 bit array gives 2^4 = 16 possible combos

Then match each literal value of the 4 bits to the ascii character code starting from lowercase A or whatever.

Comment: He wanted a specific range of characters, this way lets him define his own set if it needs changing in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = code.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) class to get the string:

```
int value = 1234;
string intString = Encoding.Default.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(value));
```

Instead of the Default encoding you can choose whichever you want.

Comment: Yeah, it's booring to keep it simple. 1234.ToString() is way to easy and not l33t!

Comment: @jgauffin, :-) The intString do not "just" become "1234". Newertheless, your comment is still funny!

Comment: hehe. You are correct. I missed the BitConverter part, but the code produces unreadable characters. Anyway. I am so sorry and hope that you can forgive me for my stupidity. I will not rest until you do so. My whole life depends upon it. PLEASE! ;)

Comment: Lol. I admit it takes some work to define the correct encoding :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

1. Base36 meets your stated requirements
2. Base64 is shorter but you have the issue of escaping the final ='s

One fundamental problem you have is that the shorter you make it, the harder it is to remember correctly.  So you need to think about whether you want this to be for copy/paste or for people to remember.

For copy/paste, I would probably go with aligned base64 given so as to avoid the equals on the end (but you could change = to _ and convert back on the server).

For human-readable, would suggest doing something else altogether.